# How to use PyAutoGUI to detect RGB values

Tags: python, macos, colors, mouse, pyautogui

I'm trying to build a small bot that clicks only certain colours. I believe `pyautogui.displayMousePosition()` should display the position of my mouse as well as the RGB values of the pixel the mouse is on. Instead, I'm only seeing the positional values (seen in the screenshot). Could this be an issue with MacOS?

[No RGB values being displayed on python console - screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTWdb.png)

Would also love to know if there's an alternate way I can go about this.

Comment: I can't find the `displayMousePosition()` function in the docs, which version are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`displayMousePosition()` is the wrong function to be using for pretty much anything besides validating that the library is functioning correctly. It doesn't return any values, all it does is print information to console. I'd strongly suggest browsing [pyautogui's documentation](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) to find out more about the functionality the library provides.

Assuming you know the screen x and y coordinates you are wanting to get the color of you'll want to take a screenshot of the screen and inspect the color values at the appropriate location.

```py
im = pyautogui.screenshot()
px = im.getpixel((x, y))
```

There is a wrapper that lets you get pixel information from a coordinate pair that you can use as well.

```py
px = pyautogui.pixel((x, y))
```

Comment: the last example should be px = pyautogui.pixel(x, y)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code to check mouse point pixel:

```
import pyautogui
import time

while 1:
    x, y = pyautogui.position()
    r,g,b = pyautogui.pixel(x, y)
    print(r,g,b)
    #time.sleep(0.1)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you failed to get the RGB value of the pixel,

you may put x y coordinate into the following to get the color code.

```
import pyautogui
PIXEL = pyautogui.screenshot(region=(x, y, 1, 1))
PIXEL.getcolors()
```